# crop object in .fits image with astropy in python

Tags: python, astropy, wcs

I trying to crop to a region in a FITS image with Astropy

I have this data to crop to a region

```
COLUMN1:    ID    [none]    Source ID
COLUMN2:    RA (core)    [degs]    Right ascension of the source core
COLUMN3:    DEC (core)    [degs]    DEcination of the source core
COLUMN4:    RA (centroid)    [degs]    Right ascension of the source centroid
COLUMN5:    DEC (centroid)    [degs]    Declination of the source centroid
COLUMN6:    FLUX    [Jy]    integrated flux density
COLUMN7:    Core frac    [none]    integrated flux density of core/total
COLUMN8:    BMAJ    [arcsec]    major axis dimension
COLUMN9:    BMIN    [arcsec]    minor axis dimension
COLUMN10:    PA    [degs]    PA (measured clockwise from the longitude-wise direction)
COLUMN11:    SIZE    [none]    1,2,3 for LAS, Gaussian, Exponential
COLUMN12:    CLASS    [none]    1,2,3 for SS-AGNs, FS-AGNs,SFGs
COLUMN13:    SELECTION    [none]  0,1 to record that the source has not/has been injected in the simulated map due to noise level
COLUMN14:    x    [none]    pixel x coordinate of the centroid, starting from 0
COLUMN15:    y    [none]    pixel y coordinate of the centroid,starting from 0
```

I don't know how crop the region with `RA,DEC`. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "crop"? What is your expected output?

Comment: i am gonna split one region from orginal .fits image with this data.

Comment: What type of data is it? Where did it come from?  Do you have an example somewhere of what you're trying to do (e.g. an image from a paper or something like that)?

Comment: for example .. i have got RA (core) == -0.02718240 , DEC (core) == -29.88018036,RA (centroid) == -0.02581738 ,  DEC (centroid) == -29.88134634.     x == 16516.367 , y ==17089.901

Comment: for above data i am gonna split region and save this image for process

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide the data in a format that is easily read into Python